# Find the closest object (before and after) to the target object

Tags: java

I want to Implement the two methods given below. **SomeObject** has a field **createdDate** of type Date

```
private SomeObject getNearestObjectBeforeTargetObjectsCreatedDate(List<SomeObject> someObjectList, SomeObject targetObject){

}


private SomeObject getNearestObjectAfterTargetObjectsCreatedDate(List<SomeObject> someObjectList, SomeObject targetObject){

}
```

Suppose I have 5 objects P1, P2, P3, P4, P5 in ascending order of created dates. And **target object is P3**, then **1st method should return P2** and **second should return P4**

Currently I have wirtten something like this

```
private SomeObject getNearestPortFolio(List<SomeObject> someObjectList, SomeObject targetObject){
    SomeObject returnObject = targetObject;

      for(SomeObject someObject : someObjectList) {
        // if the current iteration's date is "before" the target date
          if(someObject.getCreatedDate().compareTo(targetObject.getCreatedDate()) < 0) {

              if (someObject.getCreatedDate().compareTo(returnObject.getCreatedDate()) > 0){
                  returnObject = someObject;
          }

      }
     }
      return returnObject;
    }
```

Comment: Write a custom comparator and use a TreeSet?

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder: Please see my current implementation

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Make sure to make necessary changes as per your needs, but the core logic will stay the same.

```
// Note that if the target is the first element, this will return null.
private static String getNearestBefore(List<String> test, String target) {
    String returnObj = null;
    String previous = null;
    for (String someObj : test) {
        if (someObj.equals(target)) { //Insert your condition here
            returnObj = previous;
        }
        previous = someObj;
    }
    return returnObj;
}

// Note that if the target is the last element, this will return null.
private static String getNearestAfter(List<String> test, String target) {
    String returnObj = null;
    boolean nextSatisfied = false;
    for (String someObj : test) {
        if (nextSatisfied) {
            returnObj = someObj;
            break;
        }
        if (someObj.equals(target)) { //Insert your condition here
            nextSatisfied = true;
        }
    }
    return returnObj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapt the following code to your purposes. It is the equivalent for `getNearestObjectAfter`. The function returns the index of the next element which is greater than the target `key`. It is not necessary that `key` is included in the target list. Target list must be sorted.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> int upperBound(List<T> list, T key)
{
  int index = Collections.binarySearch(list, key);
  return (0 <= index) ? upperBound(list, key, index) : -index - 1;
}

protected static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> int upperBound(List<T> list, T key, int index)
{
  // -- PRE: 0 <= index < size

  int size = list.size();
  if (list instanceof RandomAccess)
  {
    while (   (++index < size)
           && (0 == list.get(index).compareTo(key)))
    {
      // -- nothing additional to do
    }
  }
  else
  {
    for ( ListIterator<? extends T> I = list.subList(++index, size).listIterator()
        ; I.hasNext()
        ; )
    {
      if (0 == I.next().compareTo(key))
      {
        ++index;
      }
      else
      {
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return index;
}
```

There is a natural extension of these two methods to "uncomparable" objects:

```
public static <T> int upperBound(List<? extends T> list, T key, Comparator<? super T> comparator)
{
  int index = Collections.binarySearch(list, key, comparator);
  return (0 <= index) ? upperBound(list, key, index, comparator) : -index - 1;
}

protected static <T> int upperBound(List<? extends T> list, T key, int index, Comparator<? super T> comparator)
{
  // -- PRE: 0 <= index < size

  int size = list.size();
  if (list instanceof RandomAccess)
  {
    while (   (++index < size)
           && (0 == comparator.compare(list.get(index), key)))
    {
      // nothing additional to do
    }
  }
  else
  {
    for ( ListIterator<? extends T> I = list.subList(++index, size).listIterator()
        ; I.hasNext()
        ; )
    {
      if (0 == comparator.compare(I.next(), key))
      {
        ++index;
      }
      else
      {
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return index;
}
```